# How to target individual components a loaded Three.js JSON object?

Tags: javascript, json, three.js

Say I have a loaded JSON file. It's a rigged (skeleton) biped character model exported from a 3D rendering software.

After I load it in Three.js using JSONLoader, is it possible to access the individual parts of this object (head, arms, legs, etc..) ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if the parts of your json model have a name attribute then you can do:

```
loaded_model.traverse( function ( child )
{
    if( child.name === "head" ) {
        // do something
    }
    else if( child.name === "left_arm" ) {
        // do something
    }
} );
```

Comment: Thanks gaitat, I will try it out.

Comment: Was able to access a child like this: if( child.geometry.bones[0].name === "head" ) {
    console.log('head');
   }     But how do I manipulate the "head" bone, e.g. change it's position? Or is it possible?

Comment: `child.geometry.bones[0].position.set( x, y, z )`. look at http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Objects/Bone (which inherits from Object3D) and http://threejs.org/docs/#Reference/Objects/SkinnedMesh

Comment: SkinnedMesh looks interesting. Will check it out. Thanks!